# Html Table Layout Desgin

Tags: jquery, html

Is this possible to make table like this picture. Can we draw line between two cells. Please give the suggestion if this is possible. Between table highlighted cells are tasks which show start and end date. Can we link these two cells like this image in HTML or j-query.

[image: table picture].

Comment: This is something related to [CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree). Check it out if it helps?

Comment: This probably would be better done with SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use a library like JSPlumb which is used to connect div-elements to each other.

```
<div id="source"></div>
<div id="target"></div>

<script>
jsPlumb.ready(function() {
   jsPlumb.connect({
        source:$('#source'),
        target:$('#target'),
        anchors: ["Right", "Left"],
        connector: ["Flowchart"]
    }); 
});
</script>
```

See this fiddle (where i have added a div to each cell to be able to style it better)

http://jsfiddle.net/nm6sfg6y/1/

Comment: Thanks Sir, It will very help full.